# Server client using python twisted

Tags: python, function, server, client, twisted

I'm very new to python and twisted. I tried to execute simple server client program. Am doing in localhost, both are in different trminal. Here what I need is, I want to call that server function "myfunc" from client terminal and also to print the value of "x" in client terminal. For that I don't know how to do and what commands to write in server and client. Please help, both codes are mentioned below. Thanks in advance.

Server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
import time
PORT = 5000
abc='Hi, Your Message Is Received'

class Server(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
            print ""
            time.sleep(3)
            print 'From Client:', data
            self.transport.write(abc)

def myfunc(x):
     print "",x

class ServerFactory(protocol.Factory):
      protocol = Server
def main():
    f = ServerFactory()
    reactor.listenTCP(PORT, f)
    reactor.callInThread(myfunc, 'Server is Ready....!')

    reactor.run()
if '__main__'==__name__:
    main()
```

Client.py

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import time
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5000
msg = 'Hello Server'


class Client(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print ""
        print 'Connection is successful'
        print ""
        print ""
        self.transport.write(msg)

    def dataReceived(self, abc):
        print 'From Server:', abc
def func(nam, idn):

        print'Client name:',nam
        print'Client Id:', idn


class ClientFactory(ClientFactory):
        protocol = Client
def main():
        f = ClientFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP(HOST, PORT, f)
        reactor.callInThread(func,'ras','90')
        reactor.run()
if '__main__'==__name__:
    main()
```

Comment: You might want to start with something simpler.  For example, write _only_ a server that you can access with a pre-existing client (telnet, Firefox, etc).  Then you only have half of the concepts to learn at once.  When you've mastered servers, then try to write your own client.  This question doesn't cover one specific issue and an answer could take many, many, many different forms (and span many pages).  Try something simpler and then ask more specific questions when you encounter issues with that.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Thanks...and if you say how to execute this problem it will be more usefull for me